# How to test neo4j.rb models with RSpec in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, jruby, neo4j

I am trying out rails, neo4j.rb and rspec for the first time, so perhaps this has a very simple solution for you knowledgeable people.
This is basically what I did:

```
(I am using jruby)
rails new graphtest -m http://andreasronge.github.com/neo4j/rails.rb
cd graphtest
bundle
rails generate model testnode
rails generate rspec:install
rspec spec/models/testnode_spec.rb
```

and then I get this error when running rspec: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x15071f28>`

I was under the impression that the neo4j.rb gem implemented active_record. I did try to include active record in various places but I never got around this error message.
What to do?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j.rb does implement a small subset of the Active Record API. You should make sure that your application does not require active record or tries to configure active record.
Not sure who adds that dependency to active record (rspec:install ?), but the rails new graphtest -m ... should work out of the box and does not have any dependencies to active record.

Comment: There is a config in the test environment file that calls active record. `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`.  It is there with the `rails new graphtest -m ...` before running rspec install.

Comment: This seems to work now, perhaps because the http://andreasronge.github.com/neo4j/rails.rb file has been updated in accordance with @Joeyjoejoejrs comment